# How to make interactive maps with plain svg

Tags: python, python-2.7, maps, interactive, kartograph

First post and new programmer. I'm trying to make a small interactive map in python and javascript using the [kartograph.org framework](http://kartograph.org/) for python 2.7 but I came across a lot of problems that stop me in the first place. 
1- I try to install the framework through

```
sudo pip install https://github.com/kartograph/kartograph.py/zipball/master -r https://raw.github.com/kartograph/kartograph.py/master/requirements.txt
```

but it gives me this error

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting https://github.com/kartograph/kartograph.py/zipball/master
  Using cached https://github.com/kartograph/kartograph.py/zipball/master
Collecting GDAL
  Using cached GDAL-3.1.0.tar.gz (592 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python2 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-Jq7Uii/GDAL/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-Jq7Uii/GDAL/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6poFbM
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-Jq7Uii/GDAL/
    Complete output (49 lines):
    WARNING: numpy not available!  Array support will not be enabled
    running egg_info
    creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6poFbM/GDAL.egg-info
    writing requirements to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6poFbM/GDAL.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6poFbM/GDAL.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6poFbM/GDAL.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6poFbM/GDAL.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6poFbM/GDAL.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-Jq7Uii/GDAL/setup.py", line 477, in <module>
        setup(**setup_kwargs)
      File "/home/roxas/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/home/roxas/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 296, in run
        self.find_sources()
      File "/home/roxas/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 303, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "/home/roxas/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 534, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "/home/roxas/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 570, in add_defaults
        sdist.add_defaults(self)
      File "/home/roxas/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/py36compat.py", line 36, in add_defaults
        self._add_defaults_ext()
      File "/home/roxas/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/py36compat.py", line 119, in _add_defaults_ext
        build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 312, in get_finalized_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-Jq7Uii/GDAL/setup.py", line 320, in finalize_options
        self.gdaldir = self.get_gdal_config('prefix')
      File "/tmp/pip-install-Jq7Uii/GDAL/setup.py", line 263, in get_gdal_config
        raise gdal_config_error(traceback_string + '\n' + msg)
    __main__.gdal_config_error: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/pip-install-Jq7Uii/GDAL/setup.py", line 257, in get_gdal_config
        return fetch_config(option)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-Jq7Uii/GDAL/setup.py", line 160, in fetch_config
        raise gdal_config_error, e""")
      File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
    gdal_config_error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

    Could not find gdal-config. Make sure you have installed the GDAL native library and development headers.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried to install GDAL from

```
pip install GDAL
```

but keeps replying with the same error. I would be glad if someone helps me

Comment: Well, as the error suggests, don't use a Python version which was superseded 20 years ago and reached formal end of life, without any future updates, 1st Jan this year. Just upgrade to Python 3.x. I think `pip install` uses Python 3.x by default (as it should since 1st Jan 2020), resulting in version errors with your 2.7 packages.

Comment: the framework is available only on 2.7, that's why I asked